# MYSQL Foreign Key Constraint failed

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables and two data sets:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    lastName VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(email)
    );
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Ratings (
    email VARCHAR(50),
    title VARCHAR(50),
    year INTEGER,
    rating INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, title, year),
    FOREIGN KEY (email)
    REFERENCES Users(email)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

and my data sets look like this. The first is loaded into Users, and the second is supposed to load into Ratings.

```
alice@def.com   Alice   Wonderland  alice   21  F   Massachusetts
bob@abc.com Bob Dylan   bdbdbd  50  M   New York
```

=======================================================================

```
alice@def.com   The Shawshank Redemption    1994    6
alice@def.com   The Dark Knight Rises   2012    10
```

I load the user's data in correctly, but when loading the ratings data, mysql says foreign key constraint fail on the foreign key reference. I don't know why it would, and I've searched for a couple hours...any insight?

the data is separated by \t . i do load data local infile ... fields terminated by \t, it works fine on that aspect. it just looks weird.

edited.

**
So I can insert one at a time at least, so maybe it's
    load data local infile
?

Comment: side note: I would use a numeric primary key and add a unique key on the email field instead of your current design. The FK look-up would be faster and the DML operations less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but are you sure the email address in Ratings exists in Users?

Comment: Maybe that there is a space before or after email address

Comment: I fixed that awhile ago. I actually was able to load it in without the foreign key constraint, but I want the two tables to be connected for the purpose of deletes so the foreign key constraint is a must.

And yeah, alice@def.com is in both datasets